# will this sql work

Tags: sql

Write ONE SQL statement that prints the name of all employees and their department numbers for all salaried employees who satisfy all of the following conditions:

1. Work on 2 projects,
2. Do not make $30000,
3. Their department manager and supervisor have the same name (Note: since name is not the pkey of employee tables, this requirement does not mean these two individuals are the same person).

Note that supervisor is not the manager of the department

SQL code:

```
select 
    ename, d#
from 
    employee, department
where 
    count(p#) = 2
    and salary < 30000
    and cname, d# in (select ename, d#
                      from employee, department
                      where employee.cname = depatment.cname);
```

Comment: What happens when you test it?  What *actual problem* have you encountered?

Comment: Looks like a homework problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  It helps a lot if you format the code (SQL) as code. It is also a good idea to identify which DBMS you are using — the answer for MySQL may be quite different from the answer for Oracle or DB2. Probably not in this case, but it is still a good idea to identify the DBMS. We also need to see an outline schema of the relevant tables. You have to be consistent in your spelling; you have `department` and `depatment` and at least one of those is wrong. It's also a bad idea to use the `FROM employee, department` implicit join.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good start for you, since there is some data missing about managers and supervisors (and generally you haven't provided any schema):

```
select ename
from employee e
join department d on e.cname = d.cname
where salary < 30000
group by ename
having count(p#) = 2
```

It will show up every employee with salary below 30K that works on 2 projects.

You're likely to need more joins/subqueries to achieve your desired output.